# Can you call an event defined in the parent window from a modal window?

Tags: wpf, events, delegates

If I declare an event handler in a separate project, subscribe to it in the parent window constructor (after the InitializeComponent call), can I trigger the event from a modal child window?  These are WPF windows.

Comment: yes, modal is only a UI construct.

Comment: `declare an event handler in a separate project` - Don't do that. `subscribe to it in the parent window constructor` - Don't do that either. `can I trigger the event from a modal child window` - Don't do that either. What are you **Really** trying to do?

Comment: don't do that - why not?  I'm trying to update a TextBlock in the parent window from the modal window while it is processing data.